# What is the word for damage to cloth caused by contact with a sharp point?

Tags: vocabulary

If you are wearing jeans and brush up against a thorn bush, the fabric may be damaged by a thorn hooking on the fabric and pulling one or more threads away from the surface of the fabric, leaving a small exposed loop of thread extruding from the cloth.

Among my family we use the term "pick" to refer to instances of this kind of damage (e.g., "my pants have a few picks in them after falling into that thorn bush"), but I do not see this usage covered in any online dictionaries.

Is there another word for this, or are the dictionaries missing a definition?

I am not looking for words that describe rips or tears. It is specifically the kind of damage described above, where one or more loops of thread are pulled.

Comment: A word or phrase request can easily attract a long list of answers when it’s too subjective – more of a poll or request for ideas. Unfortunately neither are a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. A Stack Exchange question is objective and specific enough that it has a clearly “right” answer. See: “[Real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/17/real-questions-have-answers/)”, “[Single word requests, crosswords, and the fight against mediocrity](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2160)”.

Comment: If possible, add more details of research you’ve done, especially solutions you’ve already rejected, and why. Include the desired connotation, register (formality), part of speech, and context in which it is to be used, and provide the exact enclosing sentence or passage. If this is not possible because you really do have a subjective question, a welcoming place to ask for advice is our [English Language & Usage Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95).

Comment: Pick might be the 'right' word! See https://www.apparelsearch.com/education/measurements/textiles/fabrics/picks_per_inch.html

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The word you're looking for is 'snag' (either the verb 'to snag', or as a noun, 'a snag').

The [Cambridge Online Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/snag) describes the verb:

> If you snag something, it becomes caught on a sharp object and tears
>   (eg 'be careful not to snag your sweater on the rose bushes').

The noun is:

> a tear, hole, or loose fiber in a piece of clothing or cloth caused by
>   a sharp or rough object.

It can also be used for a pulled thread or stitch, rather than for a hole or rip. A US example of this use is on the [Martha Stewart website](https://www.marthastewart.com/1506108/dont-panic-how-fix-snagged-thread), where it says:

> Don't Panic! Here's How to Fix a Snagged Thread

Comment: That definition would work, although the word I'm looking for is specifically for the case of a "loose fiber", and not a hole or tear.

Comment: @Stewart: I've just amended my answer to give an example of it being used in exactly the way you describe.

Answer (score 2):

Kiloran_speaking  has given the best term most people would refer to the loop or a loose thread on clothing as a snagged loop or snagged tread, however to allow for those that use the alternative term. [The two are often synonymous](http://drycleaningtips.com/mens-garments/fabric-pulls-snags/)

I am offering "pull" or "pulled loop" or pulled thread as [used here](https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Fix-a-Snagged-Sweater/)

"a snag is just a pulled loop in the knitted pattern"

Answer (score 2):

In my family we call it a 'loose thread'.

Edited to clarify: This is what this type of damage is referred to, due to the result. It is called this when it is damaged by this method, or by another method.

Comment: There can be many other reasons for loose threads, though, including regular wear and tear.

Comment: Despite the fact that this damage can be caused by other methods, it would still be called 'loose thread' in the OP's thorn example. Edited to clarify.

Answer (score -1):

"Pierced", Such as "I pierced my clothing or pierced my skin." "I pierced the toast."

https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/pierce

Comment: Thank you for your effort. This question was flagged by the system, mainly because it's very short. A Stack Exchange answer is lengthy enough to show that it is right. It gives explanation and context. Whatever would make it the right answer, not just an idea or suggestion.